# Отправка NFT на другой кошелёк, Javascript, Solana

Tags: javascript, web3.js

Все доброго дня и крепкого здоровья! Пытаюсь с помощью JavaScript отправить NFT-токен Solana на другой кошелёк. Проверив, какие токены есть на кошельке, получаю это:
**[{'associatedTokenAddress': 'GhpDbu3Tra5Z4TnqExRcuDPP4osNj6VuPpQ8xWMCBpHZ', 'mint': 'sZsRoUkWw4G6XbnGNrP2Htf17Nf9QKTnxKy2hynmMGr', 'name': 'TENJIN #86', 'symbol': ''}].**
Запустив код, приведённый ниже, программа выдаёт ошибку:
**Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: invalid account data for instruction**
Всю голову попереломал, не могу понять что я делаю не так. Помогите :с

```
import { Keypair, Transaction, Connection, PublicKey } from "@solana/web3.js";
import { createTransferCheckedInstruction } from "@solana/spl-token";
import bs58 from "bs58";


const connection = new Connection("https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com");


const feePayer = Keypair.fromSecretKey(
  bs58.decode("ПРИВАТНИК_МОЕГО_КОШЕЛЬКА")
);


const alice = Keypair.fromSecretKey(
  bs58.decode("ПРИВАТНИК_МОЕГО_КОШЕЛЬКА")
);

const mintPubkey = new PublicKey("sZsRoUkWw4G6XbnGNrP2Htf17Nf9QKTnxKy2hynmMGr");

const tokenAccount1Pubkey = new PublicKey("GhpDbu3Tra5Z4TnqExRcuDPP4osNj6VuPpQ8xWMCBpHZ");

const tokenAccount2Pubkey = new PublicKey("FSPU8E7Pxfot3f7xqERHfTzszJUo3tDz5pLJ1UCMDmC8");

(async () => {
  let tx = new Transaction();
  tx.add(
    createTransferCheckedInstruction(
      tokenAccount1Pubkey, // from
      mintPubkey, // mint
      tokenAccount2Pubkey, // to
      alice.publicKey, // from's owner
      1, // amount
      0 // decimals
    )
  );
  console.log(`txhash: ${await connection.sendTransaction(tx, [feePayer, alice])}`);
})();
```